# Avoiding unauthorized access to a page by changing the URL query parameter in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, url

I'm new in mvc and I have a question: If I have Index page (page with list of some object this is url http://localhost:6384/admin/) and I have actionlink button on which when user clicks he gets details of that object this is url  http://localhost:6384/Admin/Apartman/details/1.

ID of obejct is 1, but if user change value 1 to some other value he will get some other object which maybe he shouldn't be able to see it.

What can I do to protect application?

Comment: How do you determine what data a specific user is allowed to see?

Comment: Do you means second url is only callable from index page?

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it is simply checking whether the user has access to that object.

```
public ActionResult EditProfile(int id)
{      
  ApartmentViewModel objVM=MyService.GetApartment(id);
  if(objVM.CreatedById==id)
  {
     return View(objVM);
  }
  else
  {
    return View("UnAuthorized");
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other solution antiforgerytoken? could that be added to actionlink? like i said i'm really new in this :)

Comment: @user1278119: I seriously dont know. This is the way i do it.